# Bootstrap load AJAX content in Inactive Tab

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm building a site utilising Bootstrap tabs and AJAX. I've set it up so that when a link with the class of `.load` is clicked the content of that html document is loaded into the active tab, in this case `#tab2`.

This is done using the following:

```
 $(function(){
    $("#tab2").delegate('.load', 'click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

I also need some links in `#tab2`, those with the class of `.load-tab1` to load content into `#tab1`, which I have achieved with the following code.

```
 $(function(){
    $("#tab2").delegate('.load-tab1', 'click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

The problem is I can't work out how to make it so that when `.load-tab1` links are clicked the active tab is also switched from `#tab2` to `#tab1`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get it working with the following code but still thinking there is a better solution.

```
 $(function(){
    $("#tab2").delegate('.load-tab1', 'click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1").load($(this).attr("href"));
        $(".tab2").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab1").addClass("active");
        $(".tab-content #tab2").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab-content #tab1").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to do all the class toggling manually, the `$.tab('show')` method of Bootstrap plugin will do.

Answer (score 0):

You should [select the tab](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) in the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback:

```
 $(function(){
    $("#tab2").delegate('.load-tab1', 'click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1").load($(this).attr("href"), function(response, status, xhr){

          $( theFirstTabAnchorSelector ).tab('show');

        });
    });
});
```