# Ajax reloading content in Bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, apexcharts

The problem seems to lie in a few places. To start my charts I am trying to bring up in the third tab won't display the JavaScript tied to the div. I believe this is because they're set to inactive in the HTML class, which then doesn't load the charts `<div>` to display the charts.
I'm not sure the method to go about fixing this, I have looked into DOM events and Ajax load functions. But I'm not sure if that's actually the correct answer.

The ways I have tried to fix this are by making the tab active which works. But say in the future I want graphs on all three tabs, it still only loads the active tab. Also, I have tried to put the apex charts graph JS code in my click function, which also works. But again it if you click on the tabs in the order of 1 -> 2 -> 3 you will have loaded 3 charts.

All of this is using Apex charts, Bootstrap, PHP and JS.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Income categories</h3>
                <div id="chart"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Expense categories</h3>
                <div id="chart2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<!--Loads in the bar chart for analytics-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Management/scripts/incomegraph.php"); ?>
```

This is the Apex Charts

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar',
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            400,
            430,
            448,
            470,
            540]
    }],
    xaxis: {
        categories: [
            'Management Income',
            'Late Fee Income',
            'Application Fee Income',
            'Convience Fees',
            'Laundry',],
    }
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"),options);

chart.render();

var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar',
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [400, 430, 448, 470, 540]
    }],
    xaxis: {
        categories: [
            'Legal fees',
            'Utilities',
            'Cleaning and Maintenance',
            'Wages and Salaries',
            'Repairs',],
    }
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"),options);

chart.render();
```

The only error message I get is as followed:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at i.value (apexcharts:6)
    at i.value (apexcharts:6)
    at apexcharts:6
    at it (apexcharts:6)
    at new $ (apexcharts:6)
    at i.value (apexcharts:6)
    at apexcharts:6
```

I have looked at the post for help but none have sufficient answer
[Bootstrap load AJAX content in Inactive Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749144/bootstrap-load-ajax-content-in-inactive-tab)
[Reloading Content of Ajax Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687005/reloading-content-of-ajax-tab)
[bootstrap popover: reload content with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734781/bootstrap-popover-reload-content-with-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in ApexCharts which is recently fixed and released in v3.7.1
Please update ApexCharts to 3.7.1 and hopefully, the issue will resolve itself.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you, I was pulling my hair out trying to fix this! 2 days I wasted, but you are a amazing person!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. The library is very new and needs more tests to avoid such issues. Thanks for the compliment!

Comment: Oh no worries, still the best chart library out there, I would like to submit some code changes to help you out. I have a cool idea for a bar graph where it loads the totals to the right side of a chart instead of on the chart. I’m gonna try to make mine work then send it to you maybe for a example. The code is really really good, keep up the good work!!!